# WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 - Blank plain/text response when converting XML to CSV

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to transform a response from a backend-service from SOAP/XML to csv.
I do this in a returning out sequence using xslt and by setting the messageType property to "text/plain" like so:

```
<log level="full">
<property name="sequence" value="outSequence - transforming newhires xml to csv"></property>
</log>
<fastXSLT key="transform/newhires-to-csv.xslt"></fastXSLT>
<log level="full">
<property name="sequence" value="outSequence - returning response to client"></property>
</log>
<property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"></property>
<send></send>
```

If I call the proxy service in the browser, I receive an empty 200 response, with the ContentType: text/plain. The log shows:

`To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:abe469ee-a0e4-4a59-9afb-c4ad513c500f, Direction: response, sequence = outSequence - returning response to client, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"><?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>Michael,Peter,Simpson,Michael,1 Test Street,,TEST,0001,,1 Test Street,,TEST,0001,,,,MR,Male,2014-01-20Z,LTEBA,7098,EBA,G4,0,,24.58,1820,222301,MISS,A,A,Friend,A,,,,,1,1,b,1,2014-02-08Z,223173708 Wayne,G,Irwin,Wayne,1 Test Way,,TESTVILLE,0231,ACT,1 Test Way,,TESTVILLE,0231,ACT,61278963254,61412985672,MR,Male,1976-07-07Z,CSEBA,7098,EBA,G1C,1,,24.21,0,222301,MR,Snoopy,Dog,pet,kennel,022 596 3654,,,,733397,123456789,Wayne Irwin,0,2014-01-27Z,223193022 </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope></text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`

Which is clearly the transformed message in a SOAP envelope. I have uncommented out the text message builders and message transformers also so this should work.

Is there anything else I need to do to get the proxy service to correctly return a text/plain response? thanks

Comment: Can you please enable the soap tracer in the esb (http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/SOAP+Tracer) and update the question with the response message..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue by swapping the fastXSLT mediator for a standard XSLT mediator. For some reason the standard mediator doesn't include the soap envelope, but the fastXSLT does.

Answer (score 0):

with your transformation, you should generate a text node like this :

```
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">Michael,Peter,Simpson,Michael,1 Test Street,,TEST,0001,,1 Test Street,,TEST,0001,,,,MR,Male,2014-01-20Z,LTEBA,7098,EBA,G4,0,,24.58,1820,222301,MISS,A,A,Friend,A,,,,,1,1,b,1,2014-02-08Z,223173708 Wayne,G,Irwin,Wayne,1 Test Way,,TESTVILLE,0231,ACT,1 Test Way,,TESTVILLE,0231,ACT,61278963254,61412985672,MR,Male,1976-07-07Z,CSEBA,7098,EBA,G1C,1,,24.21,0,222301,MR,Snoopy,Dog,pet,kennel,022 596 3654,,,,733397,123456789,Wayne Irwin,0,2014-01-27Z,223193022</text>
```

--> remove `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` and corresponding closing tags